# Amending image zoom logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I want to set lens on preview Pane and show perfect image into zoomer div but unable to fix it. I just convert my code from some javascript example and  I'm poor in javascript thats why i need help from some experts!

my expectation like image below:

[image]

my current development like:

```js
$(function(){
$('.previewPane, #zoomer').css('background-image','url('+$('.imgkey').first().attr('src')+')');
$('.imgkey').click(function(){
$('.previewPane').css('background-image','url('+$(this).attr('src')+')');
   });
$('.previewPane').mousemove(function(ev){
$('#zoomer').css('display','inline-block');
var img = $(this).css('background-image').replace(/^url\(['"](.+)['"]\)/, '$1');
var posX = ev.offsetX ? (ev.offsetX) : ev.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
var posY = ev.offsetY ? (ev.offsetY) : ev.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
$('#zoomer').css('background-position',((-posX * 3) + "px " + (-posY * 3) + "px"));
$('#zoomer').css('background-image','url('+img+')');
   });
$('.previewPane').mouseleave(function(){$('#zoomer').css('display','none');});
  });
```

```css
.imgkey{width:50px;height:50px;border:1px solid #ddd;}
.previewPane{display:inline-block;border:1px solid #ddd;width:250px;height:250px;cursor:crosshair;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;background-size:100% 100%}
#zoomer{display:none;background-repeat:no-repeat;border:1px solid #ddd;width:250px;height:250px;z-index:1000;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
 <main>
  <div class="previewPane"></div><div id="zoomer"></div>
  <div class="imgline">
   <img class="imgkey" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0622/2101/products/product-image-496137782_800x.jpg?v=1519622126">
   <img class="imgkey" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61IPCXn13AL._SX385_.jpg">
   <img class="imgkey" src="https://http2.mlstatic.com/celular-smartphone-caterpillar-s60-negro-32-gb-D_NQ_NP_940281-MCO26572973595_122017-F.jpg">
  </div>
 </main>
```

I also try your code with simple change like : just add this two line before       "$('.preview').each(function() { " but no luck.

```
$('.img-zoom-container').html('<div class="preview"><img class="image" src="'+$('.Key').first().attr('src')+'"></div>');


$('.Key').click(function(){
    $('.img-zoom-container').html('<div class="preview"><img class="image" src="'+$(this).attr('src')+'"></div>');
});
```

and images out side of 'img-zoom-container' like:

```
<img class="Key" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_girl.jpg" width="200" height="200">
<img class="Key" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals" width="200" height="200">
<img class="Key" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch" width="200" height="200">
```

Comment: I'm sorry but what you're looking for isn't that clear. Would you mind provide some additional explanations ?

Comment: It is working for me. Are you sure you have added the CSS? [CodePen example](https://codepen.io/ijackson/pen/dqpZZV)

Comment: you can use this component. http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples its powerful and the best. hope this helped

Comment: you want to achieve image change or preview on hover the same image like (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_zoom.asp) `w3schools` example you mentioned ?

Comment: i want set 5 image to show large size with zoom effect but here have only one image how could i set more 4 small image and when i click on small image preview div change background with that image like www.aliexpress.com product zoom effect

Answer (score 2):

You have missed the CSS from W3Schools and your image src is not working,

See working snippet with multiple images.

```js
$('.preview').each(function() {
  var lens, cx, cy, img, result;
  img = $(this).find('img.image')[0];
  result = document.getElementById('result');
  /*create lens:*/
  lens = document.createElement("div");
  lens.setAttribute("class", "img-zoom-lens");
  /*insert lens:*/
  img.parentElement.insertBefore(lens, img);
  /*calculate the ratio between result DIV and lens:*/
  cx = result.offsetWidth / lens.offsetWidth;
  cy = result.offsetHeight / lens.offsetHeight;
  /*set background properties for the result DIV:*/
  
  /*execute a function when someone moves the cursor over the image, or the lens:*/
  $(lens).on('mousemove touchmove', moveLens);
  $(img).on('mousemove touchmove', moveLens);

  function getCursorPos(e) {
    var a, x = 0,
      y = 0;
    e = e || window.event;
    /*get the x and y positions of the image:*/
    a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    /*calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image:*/
    x = e.pageX - a.left;
    y = e.pageY - a.top;
    /*consider any page scrolling:*/
    x = x - window.pageXOffset;
    y = y - window.pageYOffset;
    return {
      x: x,
      y: y
    };
  }

  function moveLens(e) {
    var pos, x, y;
    result.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
      result.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * cx) + "px " + (img.height * cy) + "px";

    /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image:*/
    e.preventDefault();
    /*get the cursor's x and y positions:*/
    pos = getCursorPos(e);
    /*calculate the position of the lens:*/
    x = pos.x - (lens.offsetWidth / 2);
    y = pos.y - (lens.offsetHeight / 2);
    /*prevent the lens from being positioned outside the image:*/
    if (x > img.width - lens.offsetWidth) {
      x = img.width - lens.offsetWidth;
    }
    if (x < 0) {
      x = 0;
    }
    if (y > img.height - lens.offsetHeight) {
      y = img.height - lens.offsetHeight;
    }
    if (y < 0) {
      y = 0;
    }
    /*set the position of the lens:*/
    lens.style.left = x + "px";
    lens.style.top = y + "px";
    /*display what the lens "sees":*/
    result.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + (x * cx) + "px -" + (y * cy) + "px";
    console.log(result);
  }

})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.img-zoom-container {
  
  width: 100%
}

.preview {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.img-zoom-lens {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  /*set the size of the lens:*/
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.img-zoom-result {
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  /*set the size of the result div:*/
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
</script>

<h1>Image Zoom</h1>
<p>Mouse over the image:</p>
<div class="img-zoom-container">
  <div class="preview"><img class="image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_girl.jpg" width="200" height="200"></div>
  <div class="preview"><img class="image" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals" width="200" height="200"></div>
  <div class="preview"><img class="image" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch" width="200" height="200"></div>

</div>

<div class="img-zoom-result" id="result"></div>
```

Comment: i dont miss css! i just shorten the code. try to understand that i want 5 product image to show and then each image onclick it should show in preview div and then onmousemove it will show zoom effect. but here i'm unable to add more image set click trigger

Comment: isn't it possible to do it in only one preview div? i think now you understand

Comment: Rohan Kumar! you woked gr8 & feeling lucky that you trying to help me! i update my question details pls watch it & im sure now you can send me to success! Thanx